# Should we make this question about downgrading iOS more generic?

Tags: discussion

The question in question is [revised title] [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/downgrading-to-a-previous-ios-version). I usually just mark anything that has to do with installing different iOS versions as a duplicate of that question. The answer I have on that question covers all scenarios including upgrading and downgrading. However, the question specifically asks for a downgrade.

I come here again asking about this because of the short conversation I had with Mark on this question here that specifically asks for an iOS upgrade [Can you update an iPhone 4 on iOS 6.1.2 to 7.0.6 using an IPSW file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/133322/can-you-update-an-iphone-4-on-ios-6-1-2-to-7-0-6-using-an-ipsw-file). I tried marking that question as a duplicate of [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/downgrading-to-a-previous-ios-version), but Mark seemed to disagree with me.

The real problem is that all of these questions can be answered with my one answer.

At one point, I did make my own generic question and answered it myself, but the mods marked it as a duplicate of [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/downgrading-to-a-previous-ios-version).

Can we make this question more generic to include all unorthodox installations of iOS? If not, can I make a question that actually is generic and move my answer to it and not have it marked as a duplicate?

**Update:** Can we revisit this? We seem to get duplicates of these iOS upgrade/downgrade/reinstall questions three to four times per month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one has now answered itself.

With some simple tweaks to the original post & a massively comprehensive set of answers (& protected to stop the 'me too' contributors;-), this has become the *go-to* dupe over the past year.

I've actually just tweaked the question body itself to genericise it still further - iOS 7 is long-gone now, for most people.